# If $f,g: R^n \to R^3$, what is the derivative of the cross product $(f \times g)(\vec{a})$ where $\vec{a} \in R^n$?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

> If $f,g: R^n \to R^3$ are differentiable functions at $\vec{a}$, what is the derivative of the cross product $(f \times g)(\vec{a})$ where $\vec{a} \in E$ and $E$ is open in $R^n$?

I have deduced that for the case $n=1$, we have
$$ (f \times g)'(\vec{a}) = f'(\vec{a}) \times g(\vec{a}) + f(\vec{a}) \times g'(\vec{a}).$$

Does the case $n > 1$ need to be evaluated separately or does the above result hold for all $n$?

Comment: Do you mean $(f \times g)'(\vec{a}) = f'(\vec{a}) \times g(\vec{a}) + f(\vec{a})\times g'(\vec{a})?$. For $n>1$ what do you mean by $f'?$

Comment: Yes, corrected. For $n > 1$, I'm wondering if there is an analogous statement for functions of several variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}$In general, if $B$ is a bilinear function on $\Reals^{m}$, and if $f$, $g:\Reals^{n} \to \Reals^{m}$ are continuously-differentiable, then for all points $a$, $b$ in $\Reals^{n}$ and all vectors $u$ and $v$ in $\Reals^{n}$, there is a "Leibniz rule"
$$
\bigl[D\bigl(B(f, g)\bigr)(a, b)\bigr](u, v)
  = B\bigl(Df(a)(u), g(b)\bigr) + B\bigl(f(a), Dg(b)(v)\bigr).
$$
Indeed, $f(a + tu) = f(a) + tDf(a)(u) + o(t)$ and $g(b + tv) = g(b) + tDg(b)(v) + o(t)$, so
\begin{align*}
\bigl[D\bigl(B(f, g)\bigr)(a, b)\bigr](u, v)
  &= \frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0} B\bigl(f(a + tu), g(b + tv)\bigr) \\
  &= \frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0} B\bigl(f(a) + tDf(a)(u) + o(t), g(b) + tDg(b)(v) + o(t)\bigr) \\
  &= B\bigl(Df(a)(u), g(b)\bigr) + B\bigl(f(a), Dg(b)(v)\bigr),
\end{align*}
the final equality being a straightforward consequence of bilinearity.